# MySQL update with date manipulation from other field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a MySQL table:

```
fields:

tag
duedate
```

In "tag" field i have a string conatining a date ("MYWHATEVER_20130401").

All rows with "tag" like "MYWHATEVER_%", i need to update "duedate" now by using "20130401" from "tag" and adding 14 days and store it in format "2013-04-15".

Any way to do it with one query?

Comment: is the lenght of date fixed and located at last of the string in the column `tag`?

Comment: yes, all have exactely same format. (MYWHATEVER_YYYYMMDD)

Comment: what is the data type of column `duedate`?

Comment: column duedate is type "date"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RIGHT()` function to trim characters from a string based on specified length. Before you can add `14 days` from the string, you need to convert it first to date using `STR_TO_DATE()`, eg.

```
UPDATE  tableName
SET     duedate = STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT(tag, 8),'%Y%m%d') + INTERVAL 14 DAY
WHERE   tag LIKE 'MYWHATEVER\_%'
```

Comment: and then simply add a "WHERE tag like 'MYWHATEVER_%"?

Comment: @MichaelGrenzer exactly `:)`

Comment: you also need to escape `_` since it is a wildcard. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET
  duedate = STR_TO_DATE(tag, 'MYWHATEVER_%Y%m%d') + INTERVAL 14 DAY
WHERE
  tag LIKE 'MYWHATEVER\_%'
```

I escaped `_` on the LIKE clause because it is a jolly character.